# Data validation for cell range in active row if range contains any value

Tags: vba

I have a user form with checkboxes for language id. When checked, a cell on worksheet "output" is populated. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click()

Sheets("output").Activate

NextRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1
    If cbxEnUs Then Cells(NextRow, 3) = "3 - en-us"
    If cbxFr Then Cells(NextRow, 4) = "3 - fr"
    If cbxIt Then Cells(NextRow, 5) = "3 - it"

Sheets("input").Activate
```

I would like to apply the following data validation (from recorded macro) to each cell that receives a value.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertInformation, _
    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="3 - en-us,2 - en-us,1 - en-us"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = "Incorrect value"
    .InputMessage = "3 = action req'd" & Chr(10) & "2 = in progress" & Chr(10) & "1 = complete"
    .ErrorMessage = "Please review valid input values" & Chr(10) & "and try again"
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

How can I connect these two pieces of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the second code with the first, replacing `Selection` on the first line with `Cells(NextRow, 3)`, etc.

You'll need to split your IF statements across lines:

```
If cbxEnUs Then 
    Cells(NextRow, 3) = "3 - en-us"
    ' apply validation to this cell
    With Cells(NextRow, 3).Validation
        'etc..
    End With
End if    'etc..
```

Comment: Ha - very simple! Thanks, just what I wanted.